# Repeated execution of a jquery statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below, mentioned is a jquery code, where 'box1' is a div id and 'colors' is a class inside the modal dialog. However, it results in an unexpected behavior: When I click '.colors' for the first time, an alert box appears, but on clicking it the next time, two alert boxes appear(one after the other). That is, clicking for the nth time will result into 'n' alert boxes, one after another!

Please explain the analogous behavior and a possible solution.

```
$('#box1').click( function() {
    window.location.href='#openModal';
    $('.colors').click( function() { 
        alert('xyz');
    });     
});
```

Comment: That's what happens when you place one event handler inside another, you just keep piling on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a new `click` event to `.colors` on every click of `#box`. You need to make use of `.one()`:

```
$('#box1').one('click',function() {
    window.location.href='#openModal';
    $('.colors').on('click',function() { 
        alert('xyz');
    });
});
```

This will only assign the `click` handler for `.colors` once. If you want the ability to click `#box1` multiple times, then you need to combine your assignment with `.off()`:

```
$('#box1').on('click',function() {
    window.location.href='#openModal';
    $('.colors').off('click').on('click',function() { 
        alert('xyz');
    });
});
```

This will do allow multiple clicks of `#box1` with only one `click` handler for `.colors`, because each time it unassigns and reassigns it. I don't recommend this, though, as its a lot of extra work for the DOM to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're re-binding click to the `.colors` class every time `#box` is clicked. You could fix it by unbinding the previous click events before rebinding. Like so:

```
$('#box1').click( function() {
   window.location.href='#openModal';
   $('.colors').off('click').on('click', function() { 
      alert('xyz');
   });
});
```